# Document Tracking, Mongodb query for latest document state

Tags: json, mongodb

This is for a document tracking/management system where the system will track for the states of a document. Document states include "enrolled", "endorsed", "untracked"  etc... In my mongodb, each document state change will have an entry in the mongodb..

the following is a sample collection for doc states:

```
[//FOR DOCUMENT ONE
    {
        "document": "doc1",
        "stateName": "enrolled",
        "when": ISODate("a date when the doc state changed")
    },
    {
        "document": "doc1",
        "stateName": "mark-for-review",
        "when": ISODate("a date when the doc state changed")
    },
    {
        "document": "doc1",
        "stateName": "endorsed",
        "when": ISODate("a date when the doc state changed")
    },
    //FOR DOCUMENT TWO
    {
        "document": "doc2",
        "stateName": "endorsed",
        "when": ISODate("a date when the doc state changed")
    },
    {
        "document": "doc2",
        "stateName": "untracked",
        "when": ISODate("a date when the doc state changed")
    }
]
```

Now i want to be able to query the above collection and obtain result like the following :

```
[
    {
        "id" : "doc1",
        "state" : "endorsed"  // this should be based on the latest changed of the document1 from the 'when' column
    },
    {
        "id" : "doc2",
        "state" : "untracked" // this should be based on the latest changed of the document2 from the 'when' column
    },
]
```

Using aggregation, i can query for the latest date ("when" field) when the document has changed but i dont know how to include the actual state of the document such as "enrolled", "untracked" etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$sort` the documents by `when` in descending order, `$group` by document and take the `$first` state from it

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$sort : {"when" : -1}},
        {$group : {_id : "$document", state : {$first : "$stateName"}}}
    ]
)
```

or sort by ascending and take last state